# javascript or css3 modal box in center of screen not page

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying get a div that I have hidden to show in the middle if the screen and not the page. I want it to act like a popup modal window which I will have settings in.

The trouble is I can't get it in the middle of the screen. So if the user has scrolled down to the bottom of the page then the popup appears in the middle which they cannot see.

The popup is for a mobile webpage. Does anyone know how I would do this?

Comment: You should post your code so people can know what you have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a looking at this **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kMu4z/15/)** which is one of my answer to some other SO question.

Comment: @Keith - If it helped you mark it as an answer whenever you can thanks.

Comment: I was trying to change it what I need before I marked. I have tried to change it around but cant get it to work for me. I have a link that when click the box should appear in the middle of hr screen. The screen should not scroll but but stay when the user is, so when they close the div they are still at the bottom of the screen. http://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/EGTuk/ thanks

Comment: There was a missing bracket(`)`) in your code. Take a look at this link http://jsfiddle.net/EGTuk/2/

Comment: Thanks for help ShankarSangoli, I think I am getting tired.

Comment: One last question, works fine on desktop browser but on mobile when I scroll up of down the div moves rather than staying fixed in the middle of th screen?

Comment: I think for mobile devices you have to use `window.pageYOffset` instead of `$(document).scrollTop()`. Try this

Comment: No that is not it. Thanks anyway. The div still scrolls with the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- use `position:fixed` for non IE7- browsers whitch correctly support it;
- subscribe to `$(document).scroll(function() {})` event and update your modal box position according to `$(document).scrollTop()` value for IE